# Expand y scale but limit height of y axis line

Tags: r, ggplot2

My goal is to make a simple column chart in `ggplot2` that looks like the following chart (made in Excel):
[image]

What I'm finding is that, with example data such as this (where one percentage value is very close to 100%), my options for plotting this data in `ggplot2` leave something to be desired. In particular, I haven't found a way to make the following two simple things happen together:

1) Make the y-axis line end at 100%

and

2) Make the percentage labels over each bar visible

To address this issue, I've tried experimenting with different arguments to `scale_y_continuous()` but haven't found a way to meet both of the goals above at the same time. You can see this in the example plots and code below.

My question is: how do I expand the y scale so that my percentage labels over each data point are visible, but the y-axis line ends at 100%?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


example_df <- data_frame(Label = c("A", "B"),
                         Percent = c(0.5, 0.99))

example_plot <- example_df %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Label, y = Percent)) +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity",
                  fill = "dodgerblue4", width = .6) +
         geom_text(aes(label = percent(Percent)),
                   size = 3, vjust = -0.5) +
         scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, .5)) +
         theme_classic()
```

## Plot with desired y-axis line, but non-visible label over bar

Here is what happens when I set the limit on `scale_y_continuous()` to `c(0,1)`:

[image]

```
example_plot +
     scale_y_continuous(NULL, limits = c(0, 1.0), breaks = seq(0, 1, .2),
                        labels = function(x) scales::percent(x),
                        expand = c(0, 0)) +
     labs(title = "Y axis line looks perfect, but the label over the bar is off")
```

## Plot with y-axis line too long, but visible label over bar

And here is what happens when I set the limit on `scale_y_continuous()` to `c(0,1.05)`:

[image]

```
example_plot +
     scale_y_continuous(NULL, limits = c(0, 1.05), breaks = seq(0, 1, .2),
                        labels = function(x) scales::percent(x),
                        expand = c(0, 0)) +
     labs(title = "Y axis line is too long, but the label over the bar is visible")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the regular axis line and then use `geom_segment` to create a new one:

```
example_df %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = Label, y = Percent)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "dodgerblue4", width = .6) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(Percent)), size = 3, vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete("", expand = c(0, .5)) +
  scale_y_continuous("", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), labels = percent, limits=c(0,1.05), 
                     expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank()) +
  geom_segment(x=.5025, xend=0.5025, y=0, yend=1.002)
```

[image]

To respond to your comment: Even when it's outside the plot area, the 99% label is still being drawn, but it's "clipped", meaning that plot elements outside the plot area are masked. So, another option, still hacky, but less hacky than my original answer, is to turn off clipping so that the label appears:

```
library(grid)

p = example_df %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = Label, y = Percent)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "dodgerblue4", width = .6) +
    geom_text(aes(label = percent(Percent)), size = 3, vjust = -0.5) +
    scale_x_discrete("", expand = c(0, .5)) +
    scale_y_continuous("", breaks = seq(0, 1, .2), labels = percent, limits=c(0,1), 
                      expand=c(0,0)) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(10,0,0,0),'pt'))

# Turn off clipping
pg <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
pg$layout$clip[pg$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(pg)
```

[image]

Comment: This produces the desired plot (and is a good answer), but having to use `geom_segment()` is somewhat of a hacker-ish solution. It seems like this is such a common enough use case for `ggplot2` that there should be some way to solve the issue using just arguments to `scale_y_continuous`.

Comment: It's definitely a hack, but I don't know of a way to do this with the standard `scales` or `coord` functions. Another option is to put the numeric labels in the middle of the bars. I prefer that approach anyway, since having labels above the bars distracts a bit from the visual scale of the bar heights.

Comment: The approach of disabling the clipping is definitely less of a hack. I wonder if @hadley might be amenable to accepting a pull request for a function that disables clipping more simply, working something like `toggle_panel_clipping(my_plot, "off")`